# unable to use testrpc with ethereum wallet

Tags: solidity, contract-development, ether, ethereum-wallet-dapp, testrpc

i am trying to open ethereum wallet with testrpc to quickly test my code.
1) have opened the command prompt and entered cmd "testrpc" 
2) opened another command prompt and entered cmd ""Ethereum Wallet.exe" --rpc http://localhost:8545" , this opens ethereum wallet in PRIVATE-NET with fake accounts and ethers . 
3) however whenever i try to do a transaction or execute a contract , get error we couldn't estimate gas 
 [image]

please help as i am not able to use testrpc tool . Also while using testrpc which blocks does it sync?

Comment: were you able to find any solution?

Answer (score 1):

If you are working with truffle you could also use `truffle develop` instead of testrpc. You can start a truffle develop console with `truffle develop`. Inside the truffle develop console you can deploy your contract with `migrate`. Then you can connect your wallet with truffle develop. But you have to use port 9585 instead of 8545. `Ethereum Wallet.exe" --rpc http://localhost:9545`. But make sure you have truffle 4.0.1 installed. I will not work with earlier versions.

Comment: I am running `truffle develop` and running wallet with `$ ethereumwallet --rpc http://localhost:9545/` but still I can't create contracts, I am getting same error.

Answer (score 0):

This bug probably will be fixed by github user benjamincburns soon:

https://github.com/ethereumjs/testrpc/issues/236#issuecomment-338070203