# Can't deploy contracts on private network

Tags: solidity, contract-development, contract-deployment, testrpc, myetherwallet

I ran below command and my testrpc is Listening on localhost:8545

```
$ testrpc
```

Next, I ran below command to open ethereum wallet using testrpc network

```
$ ethereumwallet --rpc http://localhost:8545
```

Below is the screenshot of my ethereum wallet after it launches

[image: MyEthereum Wallet]

Next, I want to deploy a new contract to create a custom coin. I pasted contract code in code box and when I hit DEPLOY button it shows me below error

[image: it seems this transaction will fail]

Could you please guide what I am missing here in making an environment for testing where I can create and deploy contracts and send/receive ETHER/custom token between different wallets?

UPDATE: Also, I followed [these instructions](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/27232/unable-to-use-testrpc-with-ethereum-wallet#answer-30832) to run wallet with truffle but it also produces the same error.

UPDATE: Here is the contract code that I am trying to deploy

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.16;

interface tokenRecipient { function receiveApproval(address _from, uint256 _value, address _token, bytes _extraData) public; }

contract TokenERC20 {
    // Public variables of the token
    string public name;
    string public symbol;
    uint8 public decimals = 18;
    // 18 decimals is the strongly suggested default, avoid changing it
    uint256 public totalSupply;

    // This creates an array with all balances
    mapping (address => uint256) public balanceOf;
    mapping (address => mapping (address => uint256)) public allowance;

    // This generates a public event on the blockchain that will notify clients
    event Transfer(address indexed from, address indexed to, uint256 value);

    // This notifies clients about the amount burnt
    event Burn(address indexed from, uint256 value);

    /**
     * Constrctor function
     *
     * Initializes contract with initial supply tokens to the creator of the contract
     */
    function TokenERC20(
        uint256 initialSupply,
        string tokenName,
        string tokenSymbol
    ) public {
        totalSupply = initialSupply * 10 ** uint256(decimals);  // Update total supply with the decimal amount
        balanceOf[msg.sender] = totalSupply;                // Give the creator all initial tokens
        name = tokenName;                                   // Set the name for display purposes
        symbol = tokenSymbol;                               // Set the symbol for display purposes
    }

    /**
     * Internal transfer, only can be called by this contract
     */
    function _transfer(address _from, address _to, uint _value) internal {
        // Prevent transfer to 0x0 address. Use burn() instead
        require(_to != 0x0);
        // Check if the sender has enough
        require(balanceOf[_from] >= _value);
        // Check for overflows
        require(balanceOf[_to] + _value > balanceOf[_to]);
        // Save this for an assertion in the future
        uint previousBalances = balanceOf[_from] + balanceOf[_to];
        // Subtract from the sender
        balanceOf[_from] -= _value;
        // Add the same to the recipient
        balanceOf[_to] += _value;
        Transfer(_from, _to, _value);
        // Asserts are used to use static analysis to find bugs in your code. They should never fail
        assert(balanceOf[_from] + balanceOf[_to] == previousBalances);
    }

    /**
     * Transfer tokens
     *
     * Send `_value` tokens to `_to` from your account
     *
     * @param _to The address of the recipient
     * @param _value the amount to send
     */
    function transfer(address _to, uint256 _value) public {
        _transfer(msg.sender, _to, _value);
    }

    /**
     * Transfer tokens from other address
     *
     * Send `_value` tokens to `_to` in behalf of `_from`
     *
     * @param _from The address of the sender
     * @param _to The address of the recipient
     * @param _value the amount to send
     */
    function transferFrom(address _from, address _to, uint256 _value) public returns (bool success) {
        require(_value <= allowance[_from][msg.sender]);     // Check allowance
        allowance[_from][msg.sender] -= _value;
        _transfer(_from, _to, _value);
        return true;
    }

    /**
     * Set allowance for other address
     *
     * Allows `_spender` to spend no more than `_value` tokens in your behalf
     *
     * @param _spender The address authorized to spend
     * @param _value the max amount they can spend
     */
    function approve(address _spender, uint256 _value) public
        returns (bool success) {
        allowance[msg.sender][_spender] = _value;
        return true;
    }

    /**
     * Set allowance for other address and notify
     *
     * Allows `_spender` to spend no more than `_value` tokens in your behalf, and then ping the contract about it
     *
     * @param _spender The address authorized to spend
     * @param _value the max amount they can spend
     * @param _extraData some extra information to send to the approved contract
     */
    function approveAndCall(address _spender, uint256 _value, bytes _extraData)
        public
        returns (bool success) {
        tokenRecipient spender = tokenRecipient(_spender);
        if (approve(_spender, _value)) {
            spender.receiveApproval(msg.sender, _value, this, _extraData);
            return true;
        }
    }

    /**
     * Destroy tokens
     *
     * Remove `_value` tokens from the system irreversibly
     *
     * @param _value the amount of money to burn
     */
    function burn(uint256 _value) public returns (bool success) {
        require(balanceOf[msg.sender] >= _value);   // Check if the sender has enough
        balanceOf[msg.sender] -= _value;            // Subtract from the sender
        totalSupply -= _value;                      // Updates totalSupply
        Burn(msg.sender, _value);
        return true;
    }

    /**
     * Destroy tokens from other account
     *
     * Remove `_value` tokens from the system irreversibly on behalf of `_from`.
     *
     * @param _from the address of the sender
     * @param _value the amount of money to burn
     */
    function burnFrom(address _from, uint256 _value) public returns (bool success) {
        require(balanceOf[_from] >= _value);                // Check if the targeted balance is enough
        require(_value <= allowance[_from][msg.sender]);    // Check allowance
        balanceOf[_from] -= _value;                         // Subtract from the targeted balance
        allowance[_from][msg.sender] -= _value;             // Subtract from the sender's allowance
        totalSupply -= _value;                              // Update totalSupply
        Burn(_from, _value);
        return true;
    }
}
```

UPDATE: I tried to publish the Contract using Remix IDE (Chrome browser with Metamask extension) and here is what I get
[image: low balance error]

Comment: There's probably a problem with the contract's code. Please add it to your question so we can take a look at it.  Also, you could use Remix (https://remix.ethereum.org) for easily testing and debugging your code.

Comment: @pabloruiz55 question updated, please check contract code

Answer (score 1):

Deployed the contract and seems to be working ok.
Looking at the screenshot:

1. You should paste the code of the contract.
2. Then enter the constructor paramters in the textfield to the right of the "create" button. For example: 1000, "Token", "TKN"
3. Click on create and the contract will be deployed. You will be able to interact with it by using the functions that appear below.

[image]

Comment: Contract creation is OK but I am unable to deploy it, can't the contracts be published with fake accounts and fake ether? Do we need real ETH to deploy contracts? Because when I paste bytecode of the contract in wallet and hit DEPLOY button it shows me the error I shared in my question.

Comment: @TahirYasin This may be late and you may have already found the solution but in order to use "fake" ether you need to connect it to a test network like rinkeby or ropsnet. From there you can collect some ether from the faucets of the respective test networks and test your code out there which is better imo. Then you can change the network and deploy it live or in your private network, whichever you prefer.